# Assigning to GLfloat from incompatible type void

Tags: calloc, cocos3d

This is driving me mad. I had to GLfloat with the next assignation in the implementation of a CCNODE class that simulates watter in  side view (it comes from a Class that I found in cocos2dForum)
UPDATED:

```
-(id)initWithBounds:(CGRect)bounds count:(int)count damping:(float)damping diffusion:(float)diffusion;
{

    if((self = [super init])){
        _bounds = bounds;
        _count = count;
        _damping = damping;
        _diffusion = diffusion;

        _color = ccc4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        _h1 = calloc(_count, sizeof(float));//Here 
        _h2 = calloc(_count, sizeof(float));// And here, is where I get the error.




        WaterTexture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"watter.png"];
        //shader_ = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_Position_uColor];
        shader_ = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_PositionTexture];
        _textureLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader_->_program, "u_texture");
        texturesize= 256*CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
        offset=0;

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
free(_h1);
free(_h2);

[super dealloc];
}
```

This class is implemented in a Cocos3d Project. Before add the Box2d library, all was working fine,the water was simulated, but after add the Box2D library, XCode begin to complain saying "Asigning to GLfloat from incompatible type void"
Why is this happening? It is really rare...
Regards.
Carlos.

Comment: box2d --> did you change your implementation files to .mm extension?

Comment: Yes, i did, it is very strange.

Comment: You need to post more code (especially where you make an assignment to a GLFloat type variable) and mark the line where the error occurs.

Comment: I updated the entry with more code.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume _h1 is of type CGFloat* or CGFloat[] - if it is not a pointer type then that's one issue. The other thing is that calloc returns void* so you need to cast its return value:

```
_h1 = (CGFloat*)calloc(..);
```

That the error occurs after adding Box2D is most likely due to the Objective-C++ behaving differently than the Objective-C compiler, apparently it does not perform an implicit cast in this case, requiring you to manually add the cast. Perhaps though the compiler already warned you about it, but now it's regarded as an error (hence the advice: never ignore warnings!).

Comment: Casting it to GLFloat made it work, thanks @LearnCocos2D!! I would vote, but I have no reputation...yet!